# After a fresh install of kubuntu, error shows during boot: amdgpu: Secure display: Generic Failure

Tags: boot, kernel, kubuntu, amdgpu

I have a dual boot system with Kubuntu 23.04 and Windows 11 on Thinkpad e14 gen 2.

This error shows up after I select Kubuntu from the grub menu and also when I logout or shutdown the system.

```
amdgpu: Secure display: Generic Failure. 
amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: query secure display T
A failed. ret 0x0
```

**What I did to fix the issue:**

I did a `fwupdmgr update` and also checked for firmware updates in windows partition using lenovo vantage and lenovo support, but no firmware updates were available for my device.

Installed the latest stable kernel with mainline app, yet got this error:

**What was the output:**

```
mainline 1.4.0
Distribution: Ubuntu 23.04
Architecture: amd64
Running kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic
Found installed: linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (running)
Found installed: linux-image-generic
Found installed: linux-image-6.2.0-25-generic
Installing selected kernels:
Requested 6.4.6.
.
.
.
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-6.4.6-060406-generic (6.4.6-060406.202307241739) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.4.6-060406-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.4.6-060406-generic
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-6.4.6-060406-generic (6.4.6-060406.202307241739) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.4.6-060406-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_6_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_imu.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_4_4_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_3.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_mes_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_mes_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_mes_2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/smu_13_0_10.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p5
I: (UUID=836d0c7d-682e-4c06-826c-b35fc44a5764)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
.
.
.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
mainline: done
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers), AMDGPU proprietary drivers fits LTS Ubuntu/Kubuntu releases; probably installing Kubuntu 22.04.2 will solve your issue.

Missing firmware modules after installing AMDGPU drivers is a well known and discussed topic over the web and in most of the cases it will not compromise the efficiency of the GPU if it installs. Those modules can be handled by the drivers but are not needed for your specific GPU to work, this is why the terminal output shows WARNING messages and not ERROR messages, There are also ways you can look-up to download some of the missing firmware modules.